# C# read from SQL Server in parallel.foreach loop fails

Tags: c#, sql-server, parallel.foreach

I am trying to read data from a database and generate a XML from it. For this I have 5 SQL queries and some code to generate the XML, all in one `Parallel.Foreach` loop.

It looks like this:

```
List<int> contractIDs = new List<int>();
// ... some code to get all IDs

Parallel.ForEach(contractIDs, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 8 }, (id) =>
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("connectionString");
        connection.Open();

        SqlCommand query1 = new SqlCommand(@"some query");
        SqlCommand query2 = new SqlCommand(@"some query");
        SqlCommand query3 = new SqlCommand(@"some query");
        SqlCommand query4 = new SqlCommand(@"some query");
        SqlCommand query5 = new SqlCommand(@"some query");

        // ... some code for XML generation

        using (SqlDataReader contractTypeReader = query1.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (contractTypeReader.HasRows)
            {
                while (contractTypeReader.Read())
                {
                    // .... read from database and generate XML
                }
            }
        }

        // handle the other four queries the same way
        // ... save xml
        connection.Close();
    }
```

If I run it with `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1`, it works, but if I use more than one thread, it will randomly crash at some point with either a syntax error or an unclosed quotation.

Since the only thing that changes in the queries is the ID which is an integer and it always crashes at another point and it works an a single thread. I am assuming that there either has to be a problem with the parallel loop or the SQL Server.

**Edit**

although i don't think the problem is an incorrect sql query below is one of the queries and the corresponding error message.

```
SqlCommand contractValues = new SqlCommand(@"select cv.value, s.form_name, cp.description, test.value as pv_value
                    from dbo.contract_values cv
                    join dbo.structures s on cv.structures_id = s.id
                    join dbo.components c on s.component_id = c.id
                    join dbo.component cp on cp.id = c.component_id
                    left join (select property_values.value, property_values.structure_id, cp.*
                    from dbo.property_values
                    join component_properties cp on cp.id = property_values.component_properties_id) test on test.structure_id = s.id and test.name = 'label'
                    where cv.contracts_id = " + id + " and cp.name != 'combobox'", connection);
```

```
$exception  {"Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'combobox'.\r\nIncorrect syntax near 'combobox'."} System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
```

I know it is not a particularly safe way to handle the query with a concatenated string but in my case there is no security risk.

If I take the command text from the query which is throwing the error and run it in manually in SSMS there seems to be no problem with it.
But since it is my first time writing multi threaded code in c# I am not sure how to debug the problem.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Why do you create 5 queries and only use 1?

Comment: you run this code with try_catch, inside the `Action`, doing nothing just to see if exceptions interrupt all threads managed by `Parallel.ForeEach`?

Comment: You should use parameters in your queries. This will avoid the issues with closing quotations correctly for parameter values and will protect you from SQL injection attacks.

Comment: @PatrickTucci When using parameters it works. But is still wonder why it only was a problem when running it in parallel.